# given DE, find all other solutions from the given solution u=x

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, transformation

**(a)**  given
$$
y' = Py^2 + Qy + R.
$$
If one solution say, $ U $ of that equation is known, show that the substitution 
$$
y = \dfrac{U + 1}{ V }
$$
reduces thatequation to linear equation in terms of $V$.

**(b)** Given that  $U= x$ is a solution to equation
$$
y' = x^3 (y-x)^2 + \frac{y}{x},
$$

use the result of part **(a)** to find other solutions to this equation.

---

Well, I tried to solve part **(a)** and I came up with a linear equation 
  , but the problem is in part **b** how to find all the other solutions to this equation?? Please help.

Comment: i tried but i came up with a long equation which cannot be simplified if u can do it for me i would be appreciated bro

Comment: There is a typo in $y=\frac{U+1}{V}$ which should be $y=U+\frac{1}{V}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation $V' + \big( 2 P(x) U (x) + Q(x)\big)V  = - P(x)$ is correct.

[image]